# Extract month and year then Count and get Average with Grouping by using Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I want to extract year and month. Then I want to group by year, month and district then count rows and calculate average price for each group. Actually the SQL statement below does what I want to do. So, how can I do this with Django ORM?

```
SELECT district, month, year, COUNT(ilan_no) , TO_CHAR(AVG(price), '9999999999') as avg_price
FROM (
    SELECT 
    ilan_no,
    district,
    price,
    EXTRACT (MONTH FROM add_date) as month,
    EXTRACT (YEAR FROM add_date) as year     
    FROM ilan) as foo
GROUP BY district, month, year
ORDER BY year, month, district
```

**models.py:**

```
class Ilan(models.Model):
    ilan_no = models.IntegerField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    add_date= models.DateField()
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class IlanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ilan
        fields = ['ilan_no', 'add_date', 'district', 'price']
```

I have tried queryset below but value() method didn't work with Rest-Framework serializers.

**view.py:**

```
class IlcePriceAndSizeDistributionListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Ilan.objects.annotate(year=ExtractYear('add_date')).annotate(month=ExtractMonth('add_date')).values('district', 'year', 'month', 'ilan_no', 'add_date', 'price').annotate(
        ortalama_m2=Avg('m2_net')).annotate(ortalama=Avg('price')).annotate(count=Count('ilan_no')).order_by('year', 'month')
    serializer_class = IlanSerializer
```

Comment: run a raw query and after that just create a json from your data and return it.

Answer (score 0):

#### try this way, and let me know whether it works later.

```
from django.db.models import F, Q, Avg, Subquery, OuterRef, Count, IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth, ExtractYear
q = Ilan.objects.annotate(
        month=ExtractMonth('add_date'),
        year=ExtractYear('add_date')
    ).values('district','month','year')

qsub = q.filter(
            Q(district=OuterRef('district')),
            Q(month=OuterRef('month')),
            Q(year=OuterRef('year')),
        )

qset = q.annotate(count = Subquery(
            qsub.annotate(num = Count('year')).values('num'), 
            output_field = IntegerField)
        ).annotate(avg_price = Subquery(
            qsub.annotate(avg = Avg('price').values('avg'),
            output_field = IntegerField)
        )
    ).order_by('year', 'month', 'district')
```

#### the generated sql :

```
SELECT "myapp_ilan"."district",
       django_date_extract('month', "myapp_ilan"."add_date") AS "month",
       django_date_extract('year', "myapp_ilan"."add_date") AS "year",

  (SELECT COUNT(django_date_extract('year', U0."add_date")) AS "num"
   FROM "myapp_ilan" U0
   WHERE (U0."district" = ("myapp_ilan"."district")
          AND django_date_extract('month', U0."add_date") = (django_date_extract('month', "myapp_ilan"."add_date"))
          AND django_date_extract('year', U0."add_date") = (django_date_extract('year', "myapp_ilan"."add_date")))
   GROUP BY U0."district",
            django_date_extract('month', U0."add_date"),
            django_date_extract('year', U0."add_date")) AS "count",

  (SELECT AVG(U0."price") AS "avg"
   FROM "myapp_ilan" U0
   WHERE (U0."district" = ("myapp_ilan"."district")
          AND django_date_extract('month', U0."add_date") = (django_date_extract('month', "myapp_ilan"."add_date"))
          AND django_date_extract('year', U0."add_date") = (django_date_extract('year', "myapp_ilan"."add_date")))
   GROUP BY U0."district",
            django_date_extract('month', U0."add_date"),
            django_date_extract('year', U0."add_date")) AS "avg_price"
FROM "myapp_ilan"
ORDER BY "year" ASC,
         "month" ASC,
         "myapp_ilan"."district" ASC
```